# Junit private fields

Tags: junit, field, private

Here is an existing class and its method I am trying to mock:

```
public class ClassUndertest{

   private Object field_private = new Object();

   public Object method_public()
   {
       field_private.method();
       method_private();
   }


   private Object method_private()
   {
       ....
       return Object;
   }

}
```

My tests partially mocks ClassUndertest:

```
   ClassUndertest partialmockinstance = PowerMock.createPartialMock(ClassUndertest.class, "method_private");
```

When I run mock object:

```
 partialmockinstance.method_public();
```

field_private is not intialized and so test throws null pointer.

Is there anyway to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are initialized when a constructor is invoked. I think the default behaviour of PowerMock is to *not* invoke any constructor.

With looking at the javadoc I would try the following method instead:

```
ClassUndertest partialmockinstance = PowerMock.createPartialMockAndInvokeDefaultConstructor(ClassUndertest.class, "method_private");
```